# How to add a loading spinner on an angular universal static web application before the components loaded correctly

Tags: angular, loading, angular-universal

I have an static web application hosted on **Netlify** and for the sake of **SSR**, I have developed it with **Angular Universal**.

For a better User Experience, I want to add a **loading spinner** before all the assets are downloaded and all the components (at least the home page) are ready to go.

> The software does not have an API, so I don't think using an `interceptor` to watch the request would help.

I have written an overlay component and a service to inject it to my page, but is there something I need to do in the `app.server.module.ts` file or not?

Comment: What is the page source of your initial route(right click -> View page source)? On SSR, it wont be the usual `<body><app-root></app-root><script>...</body>`. Seeing that content would help.

Comment: Since the initial page is just the View without javascript/angular bindings and If you are using third party loading spinner, its likely its not supporting SSR/the way you have implemented has logical issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [lorenzochaudessolle](https://github.com/lorenzochaudessolle) had comment here : https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1598#issuecomment-612630028

By display the static part and hide with loading part is finished.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <!-- Here is your code (spinner, text , etc...) -->
    </div>
    <app-root>
    </app-root>
</body>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      let loader = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#loader');
      if (loader.style.display != "none") loader.style.display = "none"; //hide loader
      console.log("test view init")
    }
}
```

You can check out the link above to find more detail.

Comment: I have tried to add my custom loading component in the `index.html` file within the `app-root` component but no luck. (tried to test with a simple HTML tag, and yet nothing appeared)

Comment: It's look like you might need some more trick. https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1598#issuecomment-612630028

Comment: THanks for your response. Could you please enhance your answer so I can accept it as an answer and give you the bounty?

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `div` to the `index.html` that contains an `img` with  a base64 data `src` with an inline style that leaves it behind that app/pages when they load:

```html
<div style="...">
  <img src="data:image/gif;base64,xxxx..
```

There may be better ways, but it's an option

Comment: Could you please explain more about this approach?